# Handling an event by a Great Niece/Nephew component In Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-event-handling

It would take me days to list all the solutions I've found and tried, suffice to say I have been looking into this issue for over 8 hours now and tried everything I could find. I have no doubt that I have probably SEEN the pieces of the answer and simply lack the acumen to connect it all together.

**SCENARIO**

In my MainLayout.razor (which I have renamed AppLayout.razor) I have included a TopNavMenu component (red border) with some filter ability. I need any page that gets loaded to be able to respond to changes in the filter.

[image: Red border around the TopNavMenu component]
**AppLayout.razor**

```
<div class="page">
<TopNavMenu OnFiscalYearChange="TopNavMenu_OnFiscalYearChange"
            OnSiteIDChange="TopNavMenu_OnSiteIDChange"></TopNavMenu>

<main>
    <article class="content px-4">

            <CascadingValue Value="@OnFiscalYearChange" Name="TopNavMenu_OnFiscalYearChange">
                <CascadingValue Value="@OnSiteIDChange" Name="TopNavMenu_OnSiteIDChange">
                    @Body
                </CascadingValue>
            </CascadingValue>

    </article>
</main>
```

In order to make the even accessible to the @page component as well as any child components of the @page I have ...

1. Created EventCallbacks in the **AppLayout.razor.cs** base class (think Code Behind)
   component

   ```
   [Parameter]
   public EventCallback<int> OnFiscalYearChange { get; set; }

   [Parameter]
   public EventCallback<int> OnSiteIDChange { get; set; }
   ```
2. Created event handlers which will Invoke/Fire these
   events when called.

   ```
   public async Task TopNavMenu_OnFiscalYearChange(int fiscalYear)
   {
       await OnFiscalYearChange.InvokeAsync(fiscalYear);
   }

   public async Task TopNavMenu_OnSiteIDChange(int siteID)
   {
       await OnSiteIDChange.InvokeAsync(siteID);
   }
   ```
3. Assigned the event handlers from step #2 to the correspnding events
   of the TopNavMenu component.

   ```
   <TopNavMenu OnFiscalYearChange="TopNavMenu_OnFiscalYearChange"
               OnSiteIDChange="TopNavMenu_OnSiteIDChange">
   </TopNavMenu>
   ```
4. Then, for each EventCallback I pass a reference to all it's children
   via the CascadingValues

   ```
   <CascadingValue Value="@OnFiscalYearChange" Name="TopNavMenu_OnFiscalYearChange">
       <CascadingValue Value="@OnSiteIDChange" Name="TopNavMenu_OnSiteIDChange">
            @Body
       </CascadingValue>
   </CascadingValue>
   ```
5. So now those EventCallbacks are available to all the descendent components
6. In code behind the "page" component **Grid.razor** I have 2 methods that will handle the events when fired.

   ```
   protected async Task FiscalYearDropDown_OnChange(int selectedYear)
   {
       ... Doing something
   }

   protected async Task SiteIDDropDown_OnChange(int selectedSiteID)
   {
       ... Doing something
   }
   ```
7. In code behind the "page" component **Grid.razor** I have also added 2 CascadingParameter properties to assign these methods to the Events so that they will be called when raised.

   ```
   [CascadingParameter(Name = "TopNavMenu_OnFiscalYearChange")]
   public EventCallback<int> OnFiscalYearChange 
   { 
       set 
       { 
           EventCallback.Factory.Create<int>(this, this.FiscalYearDropDown_OnChange); 
       } 
   }


   [CascadingParameter(Name = "TopNavMenu_OnSiteIDChange")]
   public EventCallback<int> OnSiteIDChange 
   { 
       set 
       { 
           EventCallback.Factory.Create<int>(this, this.SiteIDDropDown_OnChange); 
       } 
   }
   ```

This simply does not work. The methods never get executed when the event occurs.  I have added several breakpoints and can see the properties from Step #7 getting ***set*** but after that when the event is fired execution never makes it into the event handlers (step#6).

Why aren't these event handlers getting called? Am I not assigning them correctly?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @fixmeinfortyfive for dusting off this suggestion. I had tried passing the TopNavMenu control reference as a CascadingValue before but, unlike in WebForms, you don't simply add an event handler method to the event (eg. btnTest.OnClick += btnTest_OnClick). In order for me to assign an event handler to the Event I needed to associate the EventCallbacks that I was originally attempting to use to capture the events passed down from the AppLayout.razor page, to the events defined directly on the TopNavmenu reference.

In **Grid.razor** "page" I removed the "CascadingParameter" attributes from the Event Callbacks, created a call variable to hold the references in and defined a GETTER for each ...

```
    private EventCallback<int> _onFiscalYearChange;
    public EventCallback<int> OnFiscalYearChange
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_onFiscalYearChange.HasDelegate)
            {
                _onFiscalYearChange = EventCallback.Factory.Create<int>(this, this.FiscalYearDropDown_OnChange); ;
            }

            return _onFiscalYearChange;
        }

        set 
        { 
            EventCallback.Factory.Create<int>(value, this.FiscalYearDropDown_OnChange); 
        } 
    }


    private EventCallback<int> _onSiteIDChange;
    public EventCallback<int> OnSiteIDChange
    {
        get
        {
            if(!_onSiteIDChange.HasDelegate)
            {
                _onSiteIDChange = EventCallback.Factory.Create<int>(this, this.SiteIDDropDown_OnChange); ;
            }

            return _onSiteIDChange;
        }

        set 
        { 
            EventCallback.Factory.Create<int>(value, this.SiteIDDropDown_OnChange); 
        } 
    }
```

I also added a CascadingParameter to hold the reference to the TopNavMenu component...

```
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "TopNavMenu")]
    public TopNavMenu TopNavMenu { get; set; }
```

And finally, in the OnInitializeAsync method I assigned the EventCallbacks to the event handlers of the TopNavMenu and voila! It works!

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // If the TopNav is passed in, then assign the event handlers.
        //
        if(TopNavMenu != null)
        {
            TopNavMenu.OnFiscalYearChange = OnFiscalYearChange;
            TopNavMenu.OnSiteIDChange = OnSiteIDChange;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't gone through your code thoroughly, but I can see event callbacks and cascades to try and co-ordinate activity and rendering in components.  You need to separate out your data and the events associated with it from your UI components.  The data and events belong in DI services.  Take a look at this answer that demonstrates how to use the notification pattern in Blazor.  If I get time I'll mock up an example for you tomorrow.

Comment: Not sure where to look for "this answer that demonstrates how to use the notification pattern in Blazor". Was there supposed to be a link there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EventCallback parameters defined in the AppLayout - what purpose do they serve? Surely they would never receive values, as the Layout is supposed to be wrapping your application, hence no component above them will ever pass said handlers.

As for the question - you should be passing the method that invokes the event itself, rather than the EventCallback parameters I mentioned earlier.

As in, change your cascading declarations to this:

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="@TopNavMenu_OnFiscalYearChange" Name="TopNavMenu_OnFiscalYearChange">
    @Body
</CascadingValue>
```

or perhaps even better, instead of defining multiple values like this, simply pass a reference of the TopNav component and invoke its methods - this would remove the need to define handlers in the AppLayout

```cs
<TopMav @ref="@TopNavRef" .../>

<CascadingValue Value="@TopNavRef">
    @Body
</CascadingValue>
```

Hope this helps.